# Is hard-abstraction from SDL, OpenGL, OpenAL, Freetype, etc. worth it?

Tags: c++

Is it really worth to abstract away from underlying mechanisms by means of pure virtual functions just to get rid of `#include <SDL.h>` in high-level classes? I'll still have high-level classes like Font, Canvas, Texture, but they'll use the libraries directly.

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. What is a "hard abstraction"?

Comment: Depends on the game, your target platforms, future plans, etc. Hard to give a real answer to a question so broad.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `#include <SDL.h>`? (Not saying it's a bad idea, but your true question probably lies there.)

Comment: The only good reason for most indie/hobby games to remove header dependencies is to cut down compile times; but then correct use of precompiled headers is way better than introducing unnecessary virtual interfaces and abstractions.

Comment: "Is it worth it" is a very subjective discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like pre-mature optimization to me -- not so much for execution speed here, but in terms of software architecture.

While it is true that it will be a lot harder to introduce certain abstractions after the fact, i.e., when your code base has already reached a considerable size, you have to ask yourself what you gain from introducing another layer of abstraction:

1. Is it so you could swap out libraries? (Are you ever going to do
   that?)
2. Is it so your code becomes more portable? (Are you really going to
   support multiple platforms?)
3. Etc.

I would think there's probably enough other stuff to worry about, and thus avoid introducing more complexity. If you don't already have a good reason to do it, I would say *let it go, Indiana*. Should you ever get to the point where you actually *need* such an abstraction, you could always refactor your codebase (albeit probably not without sweat and tears).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing an abstraction layer, which will just add overhead, bugs, and nonsense, make sure that you constrain all uses of the SDL types to your renderer and don't allow them to be littered throughout your code.

Careful design of where you do things, and when, will make it almost as easy to swap out renderers as If you abstracted the whole thing. But without the initial overhead.